# Accessing "About App" page for own apps

Tags: facebook, tabs

I recently created a small application to embed as a page tab on Facebook.

I've done this before, but it seems like the procedure has changed since then.

I found this page: https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=172925542764476, which says that, in order to embed the page as a page tab, I need to go to the "App About" page and click a link there.

My problem is - I can't find the "about app" page for my app! I was eventually able to determine the page for accessing my app directly (https://apps.facebook.com/[appID]/), but I don't think this is the page they're referring to. The FAQ suggests searching for the app name on Facebook, but doing so does not pull up my app.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have one, you need to create it via the 'Create page' option in the 'App Details' section of the app settings.

You don't need this page to add an app to a page, you can also use the [Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) or the [Pages API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) to add your app to a page.